# Как получить нагрузку на процессор определенным потоком\процессом в Linux

Tags: c++, linux, unix

Здравствуйте я пишу на с++. Мне надо узнать на сколько % мой текущий код грузит процессор. Как мне это узнать? Я пытаюсь искать информацию о /proc но пока ничего не нашел

Comment: используйте команду `top`

Comment: Мне это нужно для кода который будет мониторить нагрузку. Тоесть мне надо реализовать свой маленький top который буду в программе смотреть превышает ли нагрузка допустимую меру

Comment: Если кратко, то смотришь в `/proc/<PID>/stat` процессорное время → через какой-то период смотришь ещё раз → делишь процессорное время на период — получаешь процент нагрузки конкретного процесса за заданный период.... Именно так поступают все `*top`'ы.

Comment: Разве это будет время конкретного процесса? файл stat  вроде как общий вообще единственный разве там может быть  конкретный процесс ,а если может то как его узнать?

Comment: @РодионЯкутович `/proc/<PID>/stat` конечно; описка...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Большое спасибо . последний вопрос. может вы знаете какие именно значения в этом файле отвечают за процессорное время. т.к он отличается от обычного /proc/stat который явно писал cpu cpu1 и тд

Comment: на память не скажу... где-то в `man proc` это должно быть написано... вечером могу написать полноценный ответ, если ни кто не опередит...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения *процента нагрузки на процессор* данного процесса необходимо сделать два измерения *процессорного времени* (или *время процесса*) с неким промежутком, а затем разделить на длительность промежутка. В псевдокоде это будет выглядеть как:

```
MyTime_t proc_time1 = getCurrentProcessTime ();
MyTime_t monotonic_time1 = getCurrentMonotonicTime ();

waitOrDoSomething ();

MyTime_t proc_time2 = getCurrentProcessTime ();
MyTime_t monotonic_time2 = getCurrentMonotonicTime ();

PercentType processLoadPercent = (proc_time2 - proc_time1) / (monotonic_time2 - monotonic_time1);
```

### `getCurrentMonotonicTime ()`

Представляет из себя обычный запрос монотонных часов, для С++11 вполне можно использовать [`std::chrono::steady_clock::now()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock/now). Для Си следует воспользоваться системным вызовом Linux: [`clock_gettime()`](http://ru.manpages.org/clock_gettime/2) c `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.

### `getCurrentProcessTime ()`

Запрашивает текущее процессорное время.

#### Для произвольного процесса.

Для произвольного процесса с идентификатором `PID` данную информацию можно получить из файла `/proc/PID/stat`. Формат представляет из себя список значений разделённый пробелами (см. [`man 5 proc`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/proc)), например:

```
28703 (bash) S 3325 28703 28703 34823 23441 4210688 95587 249495898 324 4433 242 51 1526331 71466 20 0 1 0 78424609 22585344 1413 18446744073709551615 94750838333440 94750839090304 140728355270256 0 0 0 65536 3670020 1266777851 0 0 0 17 2 0 0 0 0 0 94750841189992 94750841211472 94750841643008 140728355272606 140728355272616 140728355272616 140728355278830 0
```

В данном случае *процессорное время* разделено на две части: *пользовательское время* (`utime`) и *системное время* (`stime`). И это соответственно значения `14` и `15`. В примере выше это `242` и `51` соответственно. Измеряется в тиках, количество тиков в секунде можно запросить с помощью [`sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sysconf).

```
long unsigned processTime = utime + stime
double processTimeInSeconds = (double) processTime / sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);
```

**Замечание:** Разбор содержимого `stat` несколько более сложная задача, чем кажется на первый взгляд т.к. имя исполняемого файла (второе значение) может включать в себя пробелы и скобки, поэтому для полноты необходимо считать весь файл и убрать всё начиная от первой открывающей скобки и до последней закрывающей и только потом считывать остальные значения начиная с 3-го.

#### Для текущего процесса/потока.

Для того чтобы узнать процессорное время текущего процесса/потока `stat` парсить не обязательно можно просто запросить его с помощью `clock_gettime()` из часов `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` или `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` соответственно. Или переносимым способом, но с гораздо меньшим разрешением с помощью обычного Си'шного [`clock()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock).

Comment: Я немного не понимаю что мы получаем в итоге и зачем нам замерять время? Допустим я проверяю интервалом в 1 секунду. получается я сразу могу получить значение нагрузки?Да и как его потом в проценты перевести?

Comment: @РодионЯкутович, если честно, немного не понимаю, что вызывает смущение... просто считаем сколько процессорного времени получил процесс за данный промежуток времени... затем делим процессорное время на длительность промежутка и получаем искомый процент нагрузки (само собой чтобы получить собственно проценты надо умножить на 100).

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726779/how-do-i-get-the-total-cpu-usage-of-an-application-from-proc-pid-stat

Вот тут все есть. Но спасибо @Fat-Zer за наводку,без него не нашел бы)

https://web.archive.org/web/20130302063336/http://www.lindevdoc.org/wiki//proc/pid/stat

а вот тут описание файла